# Using pdf() function in R, change orientation of different pages within the file

Tags: r, pdf

I am using the pdf() function generate a pdf of figures. Based on my specific data, some figures fit best in a landscape orientation, others in portrait.

I adapted the following code from here: https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/saving-plots-to-a-file-with-pdf-jpeg-and-png.html

I would like the second page to have a different orientation than the first page, but still be contained within the same file.

```
pdf(file = "/Downloads/My Plot.pdf",   # The directory you want to save the file in
    width = 8, # The width of the plot in inches
    height = 4) # The height of the plot in inches

# Step 2: Create the plot with R code
plot(x = 1:10, 
     y = 1:10)
abline(v = 0) # Additional low-level plotting commands
text(x = 0, y = 1, labels = "Random text")

plot(x = 20:40,
     y = 10:30)


# Step 3: Run dev.off() to create the file!
dev.off()
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can try rotate specific pages with [staplr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/staplr/staplr.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that can be considered :

```
library(qpdf)

pdf(file = "C:/pdf1.pdf",   # The directory you want to save the file in
    width = 8.5, # The width of the plot in inches
    height = 11.5) # The height of the plot in inches

# Step 2: Create the plot with R code
plot(x = 1:10, 
     y = 1:10)
abline(v = 0) # Additional low-level plotting commands
text(x = 0, y = 1, labels = "Random text")

dev.off()

pdf(file = "C:/pdf2.pdf",   # The directory you want to save the file in
    width = 14, # The width of the plot in inches
    height = 8.5) # The height of the plot in inches

plot(x = 20:40,
     y = 10:30)

# Step 3: Run dev.off() to create the file!
dev.off()

pdf_combine(input = c("C:/pdf1.pdf", "C:/pdf2.pdf"), "C:/pdf3.pdf")
```